# Can Chrome Developer Tools copy element by ID

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Developer Tools command console provides a handy command : `copy()`. From example, I can `copy(document.body)`. However, is there any way to copy an element by ID? Like `copy('#elementID')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the $ function has not been overridden, you can use it.

```
copy($("elementId"));
```

Otherwise, if the element id does not contain special characters, you can just write the id out.

```
copy(elementId); //No quotes
```

If the element id does contain special characters, you will have to use document.getElementById.

```
copy(document.getElementById("elementId"));
```